# Stripe PHP Redirect after Purchase

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I just want to add a redirect to a certain url after purchase by using the Stripe API for PHP. My approach so far is:

```
$link = $stripe->paymentLinks->create([
    'line_items' => [
        [
        'price' => $product['default_price'],
        'quantity' => 1,
        ],  
    ],
    'after_completion' => [
        [
            'redirect' => [
            'url' => 'https://www.trainer-va.de/Trainer-Cloud/123.php?product=' . $product['default_price'] . '',
        ],
        'type' => 'redirect'
    ],

]);
```

but it's not working. Any hints what's going wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [What do you mean "It doesn't work"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147616/what-do-you-mean-it-doesnt-work)

Comment: it throws an empty PHP page without any error message. Even by using
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: You mean when you execute the exact code above? Have you looked in your browser's network tool to see if any redirection happens? Does the browser ever try to visit `https://www.trainer-va.de/Trainer-Cloud/123.php` or not? It's unclear, from your description.

Comment: there seems to be an error in the JSON object notation, can you check it?

Comment: What JSON notation? You haven't shown any. Again, please try to be more specific and give proper details of whatever you are discussing. It's very hard to help when you only give vague or incomplete details. Thanks.

Comment: 'after_completion' => [
        [
            'redirect' => [
            'url' => 'https://www.trainer-va.de/Trainer-Cloud/123.php?product=' . $product['default_price'] . '',
        ],
        'type' => 'redirect'
    ],

Comment: there is the error, but I don't know which part throws it, it seems a syntax error

Comment: According to https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-links/api#tracking-payments, you need to send `after_completion[redirect][url]`, but you created `after_completion[0][redirect][url]` - you got one level of array-ness to much here.

Comment: None of this is JSON, though, that's what confused me, it's just a regular PHP array. Anyway... `it seems a syntax error`...well have you got PHP error reporting switched on? Or error logging to a file? If there's a syntax error, you'll see it on screen or in the error log file (depending on your configuration). If you haven't got either of those switched on...well why not??

Comment: yes, I turned on PHP Error Reporting

Comment: CBroe, can you help me further?

Comment: You got one pair of [...] too many there.

Comment: ok, I fixed it, still not working

Comment: As CBroe said, you should just remove the unnecessary extra level of array around the "redirect" property: `'after_completion' => [ 'redirect' => [ 'url' => 'https://www.trainer-va.de/Trainer-Cloud/123.php?product=' . $product['default_price'], 'type' => 'redirect']`. The "type" and "redirect" options are supposed to be at the same level in the data structure, as shown in the example in the documentation. Also `. ''` has no useful purpose, so I removed that as well - what's the point of appending nothing to a string?

Comment: _"it throws an empty PHP page"_ - can you expand on that? _What_ does? Does your code above result in an empty page? Or are you able to create the link, and when you use it and make the payment, it redirects back to your site, and you get an empty page there then? If the latter, did it go to the redirect URL you specified here, or elsewhere?

Comment: ^^^ I already asked this 25 minutes ago and got no response. But it's important to know - we cannot see your screen or run your code, so you need to give detailed and accurate info for us to help you properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request body is malformatted at the after_completion attribute level[1].

You should do like this instead:

```
$link = $stripe->paymentLinks->create([
   'line_items' => [
       [
       'price' => $product['default_price'],
       'quantity' => 1,
       ], 
   ],
   'after_completion' => [
       'redirect' => [
           'url' => 'https://www.trainer-va.de/Trainer-Cloud/123.php?product=' . $product['default_price'] . '',
       ],
       'type' => 'redirect'
   ],
]);
```

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_links/payment_links/create#create_payment_link-after_completion